lavaan probit model: calculation of simple slopes and std. error
I am trying to implement the calculation for simple slopes estimation for probit models in lavaan as it is currently not support in semTools.
The idea is to be able to plot the slope of a regression coefficient and the corresponding CI. So far, we can achieve this in lavaan + emmeans using a linear probability model.

library(semTools)
library(lavaan)
library(emmeans)
library(ggplot2)
# Load the PoliticalDemocracy dataset
data("PoliticalDemocracy")

# Create a binary indicator for dem60 (e.g., using median as a threshold)
PoliticalDemocracy$dem60_bin <- ifelse(PoliticalDemocracy$y1 >= mean(PoliticalDemocracy$y1), 1, 0)




### LPM

model <- '
  # Latent variable definition
  ind60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
  # Probit regression with ind60 predicting dem60_bin
  dem60_bin ~ b*ind60

'

# Fit the model using WLSMV estimator for binary outcomes
fit <- sem(model, data = PoliticalDemocracy, meanstructure=TRUE)

summary(fit)

slope <- emmeans(fit, "ind60", 
                 lavaan.DV = "dem60_bin", 
                 at = list(ind60 = seq(-2, 2, 0.01)),
                 rg.limit = 60000)|> data.frame()

# Plot the marginal effect of the latent variable ind60 with standard errors
ggplot(slope, aes(x = ind60, y = emmean)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = asymp.LCL, ymax = asymp.UCL), 
              alpha = 0.2, fill = "lightblue") +
  labs(
    title = "Marginal Effect of ind60 (Latent Variable) on the Predicted Probability of dem60_bin",
    x = "ind60 (Latent Variable)",
    y = "Marginal Effect of ind60"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

However, semTools does not support any link function at this point so I have to relay on manual calculations to obtain the predicted probabilities. So far, I am able to estimate the change in probability for the slope and the marginal probabilities. However, I am pretty sure that the way I am calculating the SE is wrong as they too small compared to the lpm model. any advice on this is highly appreciated.

### PROBIT LINK 
# Define the probit model with ind60 as a latent variable
model <- '
  # Latent variable definition
  ind60 =~ y1 + y2 + y3 + y4
  # intercept/threeshold
  dem60_bin|"t1"*t1

  # Probit regression with ind60 predicting dem60_bin
  dem60_bin ~ b*ind60
  # the slope exprssed in probabilities
  slope :=  pnorm(-t1)*b

'

# Fit the model using WLSMV estimator for binary outcomes
fit <- sem(model, data = PoliticalDemocracy, ordered = "dem60_bin", estimator = "WLSMV")
summary(fit)
# Extract model coefficients
coef_fit <- coef(fit)
intercept <- coef_fit["t1"]
beta_ind60 <- coef_fit["b"]
params <- parameterEstimates(fit)
se_beta_ind60 <- params[params$label == "b", "se"]

# Define a range of ind60 values for the marginal effect calculation
# Here, we will use the predicted values from the latent variable
ind60_seq <- seq(-2, 2, length.out = 100)  # Assuming a standard range for latent variable

# Calculate marginal effects for each value of ind60 in ind60_seq
marginal_effects_ind60 <- sapply(ind60_seq, function(ind60_value) {
  # Linear predictor for given ind60_value
  linear_predictor <- -intercept + (beta_ind60 * ind60_value)
  pdf_value <- pnorm(linear_predictor)
  #marginal_effect <- pdf_value * beta_ind60
  return(pdf_value)
})


# Standard errors for marginal effects using the Delta Method
se_marginal_effects <- sapply(ind60_seq, function(ind60_value) {
  # Linear predictor for given ind60_value
  linear_predictor <- -intercept + beta_ind60 * ind60_value
  pdf_value <- dnorm(linear_predictor)
  
  # Delta Method: SE = |f'(x)| * SE(beta)
  marginal_effect_se <- abs(pdf_value) * se_beta_ind60
  return(marginal_effect_se)
})


plot_data <- data.frame(ind60 = ind60_seq, marginal_effect = marginal_effects_ind60, se_marginal_effect = se_marginal_effects)

# Plot the marginal effect of the latent variable ind60 with standard errors
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = ind60, y = marginal_effect)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = marginal_effect - 1.96 * se_marginal_effect, ymax = marginal_effect + 1.96 * se_marginal_effect), 
              alpha = 0.2, fill = "lightblue") +
  labs(
    title = "Marginal Effect of ind60 (Latent Variable) on the Predicted Probability of dem60_bin",
    x = "ind60 (Latent Variable)",
    y = "Marginal Effect of ind60"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()

